# Change select options depending on another select

Tags: javascript, html

I have two selects and the second one should change his values depending on selected value in the first one

I have something like this but it doesn't work:

```js
var lookup = {
       'Option 1': ['Option 1 - Choice 1', 'Option 1 - Choice 2', 'Option 1 - Choice 3'],
       'Option 2': ['Option 2 - Choice 1', 'Option 2 - Choice 2'],
       'Option 3': ['Option 3 - Choice 1'],
    };
    
$('#options').on('change', function() {
       
       var selectValue = $(this).val();
    
       $('#choices').empty();
       
       for (i = 0; i < lookup[selectValue].length; i++) {
          
          $('#choices').append("<option value='" + lookup[selectValue][i] + "'>" + lookup[selectValue][i] + "</option>");
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="options">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="choices">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select an option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The code looks good on first glance. Tried it in codepen and it indeed works as intended. Can you open your browser's developer console and see what it shows?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine for me. So, it might be that you're js is somehow not executing or jQuery isn't being loaded in properly, have you tried console logging in the onChange event?

Also, I made some minor improvements to your code.

```
$("#options").on("change", function () {
  var selectValue = $(this).val();
  var options = lookup[selectValue].map(
    (v) => `<option value="${v}">${v}</option>`
  );
  
  $("#choices").html(options.join("\n"));
});
```

Notice that instead of appending each element, we're preparing the string and then manipulating the DOM only once at the end. This is more efficient.

The rest of your code is fine

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer if it has helped you?